# I am unable to load CSS and script files in my codeigniter application, getting 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to setup a codeigniter application, codeigniter version used is **2.1.3**.

Application name is "**CodeIgniter-2.1.3**" and it is located in the path "**C:\Users\myuser\Documents\CodeIgniter-2.1.3**"

And the folder structure is[image: Folder Structure of my CodeIgniter application]

And the **"index.php" file is located inside "htdocs" folder**, for security purpose. And my CSS and script files are placed inside "**htdocs/assets**" folder. Pictorial representation of it:
[image: Pictorial representation of htdocs folder]

Since I am using Apache Web Server, I have written vhost, that contains the .htaccess for the application too.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/CodeIgniter-2.1.3/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost-raw
    ServerAlias localhost-raw
    ErrorLog "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/CodeIgniter-2.1.3/CodeIgniter-2.1.3-error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/CodeIgniter-2.1.3/CodeIgniter-2.1.3-access.log" common
    <Directory   "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/CodeIgniter-2.1.3/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
        Require all granted
   </Directory> 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The htaccess allows me to access my website without "index.php" in the URL, but I am not able to load any CSS and script files.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

[image: This is how my test page is rendering]

Comment: _Probably not your problem but_ If you are going to do `Require all granted` there is little point also having a `Require all denied` just before it

Comment: Check your main `index.php` file and verify that the variables `$system_path`, `$application_folder` and `$view_folder` are correctly configured. Since your `index.php` is within a directory which is not expected by CI, this could be the issue

Comment: What would be correct $system_path, $application_folder to my application.
I have mentioned like this:
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';

And where to check the $view_folder?